# AWS Athena Query 2 separate tables together

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, query

I have 2 Tables, and i need to query them together, for example.
From the first table i get results with my query:
InstanceID, title, status and etc...

From the second one:
key, value, region and etc...

I want to make 1 query so i can get the results from both of them.

**My 1st query:**

```
SELECT id, status, title, resourceid, accountid
FROM test.awstest01 
WHERE status = 'NoTest' 
AND compliancetype = 'Closed' ORDER BY 1 DESC limit 1000;
```

**2nd query:**

```
SELECT key, value, region
FROM "test777"."awstest05" 
WHERE value = 'Program'
limit 1000;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue with  **INNER JOIN**

Added INNER JOIN to my query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).